# how to add wpf mediakit to my project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, media-player, wpf-mediakit

I referenced WPFMediaKit.dll to my project and this is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCameraTest.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Controls:VideoCaptureElement ></Controls:VideoCaptureElement>
</Grid>
```

But i get the error:

> The name "VideoCaptureElement" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit".

What i'm skipping?

Answer (score 0):

1. is it possible that you write VideoCaptureElement wrong !?!?! you write: VideoCaputreElemnt
2. and i think you must call it with `<WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement >`

Comment: Thanks for your response 1. "VideoCaptureElement" was a mistake after trying many things without success but it is not the problem ;) 2. "The type 'WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement' was not found"

Answer (score 0):

See the wiki entry here:
https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/wiki

```
<WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement
 x:Name="videoCapElement"
 LoadedBehavior="Play"
 DesiredPixelWidth="320"
 DesiredPixelHeight="240"
 Stretch="Fill"
 VideoCaptureSource="{Binding Path=CaptureDeviceName}"
 FPS="30"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Controls:VideoCaptureElement>` works for me~

Have you added "WPF MediaKit" reference to your project?
And make sure "VideoCaptureElement.cs" exists in WPF MediaKit?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a reference by dll file.

Use Nuget Package and look for WPFMediaKit and add this.